# How to clear/update a plot in a children widget from a parent frame in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to find out how to clear a plot in a canvas (in tkinter) that is a children of a frame. My problem is that this happens inside a show() function in a different class from the one that created the frame. So the idea about show() is that it will be called many times and instead of destroying the widget and creating everything from scratch each time that show() is called, I would like that the plot inside the canvas which is a children of a frame is cleared/updated but the widget is preserved.

This might be easier to understand in pseudo code perhaps:

```
class A():
    def__init__(self, master):
        sframe = Frame(master)
        sframe.pack(side=RIGHT)
        f = Figure(figsize=(3,2), dpi=100)

        a = f.add_subplot(122);
        # initially plots a sine wave 
        t = arange(0.0, 1, 0.01);
        s = sin(2*pi*t);
        a.plot(t,s);

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=sframe)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        # now i create the other object that will call show()
        data_obj = B(sframe)


class B():
    ...
    show(self, frame):
       _wlist = frame.winfo_children()
       for item in _wlist:
           item.clear() # or something like this
       # and then re-plot something or update the current plot
```

The last part of the code is where I have some problems. I am not sure how to clear the widget in the frame. How do I know which type of widget it is and how do I clear it or update it? I get:

```
*** AttributeError: Canvas instance has no attribute 'clear'
```

Any ideas are more than welcome. Many thanks!

Comment: Nobody? Any ideas where to look for something like this?

Comment: I solved this by clearing the axis associated to the figure in the frame. Originally I wanted to access the figure and its axis using the frame. However, I have not found a way to do this, so I added the axis to the frame before passing it to the constructor of class B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of clearing the child of the frame, which is of class Canvas (using winfo_class()), I passed the axis of the figure in the frame and also passed the canvas.

In class A:

```
frame.canvas = canvas
frame.ax = a
```

Then when in class B we clear the axis using the frame to access it, update it and show the canvas:

```
self.sframe.ax.clear()
self.sframe.ax.plot(newline)
self.sframe.canvas.show()
```

If you know a way to access the axis by navigating through the children of the frame, let me know...